# sqlalchemy update records in a case of a primary key conflict, when the primary key is flexiable

Tags: sqlalchemy, primary-key

I have the following records in MySQL DB
for convenience, I am writing it as a JSON:

```
{
'CUSTNAME': '6813482975524',
'CDES': 'Derek Bros',
'NAME': None,
'IVDATE': '2023-03-28T00:00:00+03:00',
'IVNUM': 'T1000024',
'FINAL': None,
'STATDES': 'Draft',
'OWNERLOGIN': 'tp3',
'ORDNAME': 'SO23000426'}
```

The fields "CUSTNAME" is a primary key in the MySQL DB.
I want to update the record in the DB with this one:
(the "FINAL" and STATDES" are different)

```
 row = {
'CUSTNAME': '6813482975524',
'CDES': 'Derek Bros',
'NAME': None,
'IVDATE': '2023-03-28T00:00:00+03:00',
'IVNUM': 'T1000024',
'FINAL': Yes,
'STATDES': 'Final',
'OWNERLOGIN': 'tp3',
'ORDNAME': 'SO23000426'
```

}

I want to write a sqlalchemy update statement that update the record
According to SQLAlchemy documentation, the update is statement is:

```
UpdateStmt = update(TableObject).where(TableObject.c.CUSTNAME == row['CUSTNAME']).values(row)
```

When I tried the code above, it's work great!

I want that the primary key name will be taken from a variable and not hardcoded in the code.

```
table_pk = TableObject.primary_key.columns.values()[0].name
UpdateStmt = update(TableObject).where(TableObject.c.table_pk == row['CUSTNAME']).values(row)
```

I tried using str(table_pk) and eval(table_pk) and nothing work

any idea how should I do it?

Comment: Try `TableObject.c[table_pk]`

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.